# C sharp code to fetch WMI information

Tags: c#

how do you code in c sharp to fetch WMI information like total memory,cpu usage with the use of "performance counter".

Comment: try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26310/Using-WMI-to-retrieve-processor-information-in-C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private static PerformanceCounter cpuCounter;
private static PerformanceCounter memoryCounter;

[...]

cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter
{
   CategoryName = "Processor",
   CounterName = "% Processor Time",
   InstanceName = "_Total"
};


memoryCounter = new PerformanceCounter
{
    CategoryName = "Memory",
    CounterName = "Available Bytes"
};

[...]

public double CpuUsage
{
   get
   {
      lock (lockToken)
      {
          return Math.Round(cpuCounter.NextValue(), 2);
      }
   }
 }

 public double MemoryUsage
 {
    get
    {
       lock (lockToken)
       {
          return Math.Round(memoryCounter.NextValue() / totalMemory * 100, 2);
       }
    }
  }
```

Total Memory:

```
 using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT totalphysicalmemory FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"))
        {
            using (var wmiData = searcher.Get())
            {
                foreach (var mo in wmiData)
                {
                    totalMemory = long.Parse(mo["totalphysicalmemory"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

To get the virtual memory you'll have to do some research by yourself.

Comment: thanks a ton.How do you fetch total available memory and virtual memory.